# Flutter Countdown

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'd like to create a timer for a flutter website that counts down to a certain date.

e.g.

`120` Days `12` Hours `45` Mins `15` Secs

Is that possible and can anyone help?

I haven't got a clue where to start with this one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this package
https://pub.dev/packages/countdown_flutter

Note: In this package you will see a duration property. You should locate time difference between nowDate and the other date

```
 var nextDate = DateTime(2023, 10, 29);
 var nowDate = DateTime.now();
 var difference = nowDate.difference(nextDate);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Can you elaborate a little and possibly show a working example? I tried with this package yesterday but i ended up with something that either didn't have days (in the formatted version), or every "remaining" was the entire duration.

e.g.

```120 days  40983 hours 9823798723 minutes 98723987432 seconds```

Comment: Ok, so I get what you mean now by using the difference var for the duration - thanks for that! But now I'm having this problem ```4635:54:33```